# Golang WaitGroup.Done() being skipped

Tags: go, concurrency, delve

I've got a function that relies on checking some errors concurrently and I'm trying to use waitgroups to wait until all processes that return possible errors are done before I check all the errors.

It seems to be skipping some of the wg.Done() cals. Here's a youtube video of the debug (it loops through the 'for' loop 3 times, sorry):
[Golang Delve Debug for WaitGroups](https://youtu.be/yRAWHGhDp-8)

Any idea why it'd be skipping some of the waitgroup.Done() calls?

Here's the code:

```
package controllers

import (
    "errors"
    "mobilebid/billable"
    db "mobilebid/database"
    "mobilebid/stripe"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "sync"
    "time"

    log "github.com/Sirupsen/logrus"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

var (
    errBillableID     = errors.New("It looks like there was an error while getting your billable ID. Do you have a credit card set up?")
    errWinningItems   = errors.New("It looks like there was an error while gathering your winning items. Please contact an event rep.")
    errAcctInfo       = errors.New("We had some trouble getting the account information for the event. Please contact an event rep.")
    errLoggingTrans   = errors.New("It looks like we had some sort of issue while logging your transaction. Please contact an event rep.")
    errParsingURL     = errors.New("We had some issue looking at the URL.")
    errStripeIssue    = errors.New("It looks like there was some kind of issue while talking with Stripe. If you were in the middle of a transaction, this doesn't mean the transaction was cancelled. Take a look at your transactions and/or contact an event rep.")
    errItemsPurchased = errors.New("One or more of the items you're trying to purchase have already been purchased. If this doesn't sound right, please contact an event rep.")
)

func createLogCtx(bidderID, eventID int) *log.Entry {
    return log.WithFields(log.Fields{
        "bidderID": bidderID,
        "eventID":  eventID,
    })
}

var wg sync.WaitGroup

const gorutineCt = 6

//PurchaseItems purchases items from the event for the bidder and sends the funds to the customer
//  In order for PurchaseItems to work:
//      1. Bidder must have a customer account set up in Stripe
//      2. Event owner needs to have their Stripe registered with the apps Stripe account
//      3. Item must not have been purchased before (ever)
func PurchaseItems(dB db.AppDB) http.HandlerFunc {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {

        ps := mux.Vars(req)

        eventID, err := strconv.Atoi(ps["eventID"])
        if err != nil {
            log.Error(err.Error())
            res.Write(ResErr(errParsingURL.Error()))
            return
        }

        bidderID, err := strconv.Atoi(ps["bidderID"])
        if err != nil {
            log.Error(err.Error())
            res.Write(ResErr(errParsingURL.Error()))
            return
        }

        itemsChan := make(chan []db.ItemWon)
        billableBidderIDChan := make(chan string)
        creditableAcctChan := make(chan string)
        errsChan := make(chan error, gorutineCt)
        wg.Add(gorutineCt)

        logCtx := createLogCtx(bidderID, eventID)

        acct := stripe.New(os.Getenv("SECRET_KEY"), os.Getenv("PUBLISHABLE_KEY"))

        go func() {
            id, e := dB.GetBidderBillableID(bidderID)
            if e != nil {
                logCtx.Error(e.Error())
                errsChan <- errBillableID
                billableBidderIDChan <- id
            } else {
                errsChan <- nil
                billableBidderIDChan <- id
            }
            wg.Done()
        }()

        go func() {
            i, e := dB.GetWinningItemsForBidder(bidderID, eventID)
            if e != nil {
                logCtx.Error(e.Error())
                errsChan <- errWinningItems
                itemsChan <- i
            } else {
                errsChan <- nil
                itemsChan <- i
            }
            wg.Done()
        }()

        go func() {
            a, e := dB.GetCreditableAccountFromEvent(eventID)
            if e != nil {
                logCtx.Error(e.Error())
                errsChan <- errAcctInfo
                creditableAcctChan <- a
            } else {
                errsChan <- nil
                creditableAcctChan <- a
            }
            wg.Done()
        }()

        go func() {
            items := <-itemsChan
            for _, val := range items {
                e := dB.CheckIfItemPurchased(val.ItemID)
                if e != nil {
                    logCtx.WithFields(log.Fields{
                        "itemID":     val.ItemID,
                        "_timestamp": time.Now(),
                    }).Error(e.Error())
                    errsChan <- errItemsPurchased
                    itemsChan <- items
                    wg.Done()
                    return
                }
            }
            errsChan <- nil
            itemsChan <- items
            wg.Done() //SKIPPED
        }()

        go func() {
            billableBidderID := <-billableBidderIDChan
            e := acct.BuyerIsBillable(billableBidderID)
            if e != nil {
                logCtx.Error(e.Error())
                errsChan <- errStripeIssue
                billableBidderIDChan <- billableBidderID
            } else {
                errsChan <- nil
                billableBidderIDChan <- billableBidderID
            }
            wg.Done()
        }()

        go func() {
            creditableAcct := <-creditableAcctChan
            e := acct.CanReceiveFunds(creditableAcct)
            if e != nil {
                logCtx.Error(e.Error())
                errsChan <- errStripeIssue
                creditableAcctChan <- creditableAcct
            } else {
                errsChan <- nil
                creditableAcctChan <- creditableAcct
            }
            wg.Done()
        }()

        wg.Wait()
        close(errsChan)

        if err = checkConcurrentErrs(errsChan); err != nil {
            logCtx.Error(err.Error())
            res.Write(ResErr(err.Error()))
            return
        }

        items := <-itemsChan
        amount := addItems(items)
        appFee := calculateFee(amount, .03) //TODO: Store this somewhere where it can be edited without having to restart the app.

        invoice := billable.BillObject{
            Desc:     "Test Charge", //TODO: Generate this description from the event, items and bidder somehow.
            Amount:   amount,
            Currency: "usd",
            Dest:     <-creditableAcctChan,
            Fee:      appFee,
            Meta:     createItemsList(items),
            Customer: <-billableBidderIDChan,
        }

        trans, err := acct.ChargeBidder(invoice)
        if err != nil {
            logCtx.Error(err.Error())
            res.Write(ResErr(errStripeIssue.Error()))
            return
        }

        logCtx.WithFields(log.Fields{
            "stripeTransID": trans.TransID,
            "itemcCount":    len(items),
        }).Info("Transferred funds from bidder to client")

        dbTrans := db.Transaction{
            TransID:  trans.TransID,
            UserID:   5,
            BidderID: bidderID,
            EventID:  eventID,
            Amount:   int64(amount),
            AppFee:   int64(appFee),
            Desc:     "Some test order",
            Status:   "completed",
        }

        orderID, err := dB.InsertTransaction(dbTrans)
        if err != nil {
            logCtx.WithFields(log.Fields{
                "stripeTransID": dbTrans.TransID,
                "_timestamp":    time.Now(),
            }).Error(err.Error())
            res.Write(ResErr(errLoggingTrans.Error()))
            return
        }

        for it, val := range items {
            i := db.TransactionLine{
                OrderID: orderID,
                ItemID:  val.ItemID,
                Amount:  uint64(val.Bid * 100), //Must do this since the bid is in dollars but the amount is pennies
                Line:    it,
            }

            err := dB.InsertTransactionLine(i)
            if err != nil {
                logCtx.WithFields(log.Fields{
                    "stripeTransID": dbTrans.TransID,
                    "lineNumber":    i,
                    "_timestamp":    time.Now(),
                }).Error(err.Error())
                res.Write(ResErr(errLoggingTrans.Error()))
                return
            }
        }

        logCtx.WithField("orderID", orderID).Info("Order created")

        //TODO: Send receipt to buyer.
        res.Write(ResOK(trans.TransID))

    })
}
```

Comment: For starters, always put the `wg.Add(1)` right before the `go ` call, and `defer wg.Done()`. This way each add is local to the function so you don't need to keep an accurate count, and the defer ensures Done is always called correctly.

Comment: When I do that, the moment one is done, it hits the wg.Wait which is now 0, then closes the channel, then I get a panic for sending on a closed channel. Code:

    `go func() {
   wg.Add(1)
   defer wg.Done()
   items := <-itemsChan
   for _, val := range items {
    e := dB.CheckIfItemPurchased(val.ItemID)
    if e != nil {
     logCtx.WithFields(log.Fields{
      "itemID":     val.ItemID,
      "_timestamp": time.Now(),
     }).Error(e.Error())
     errsChan <- errItemsPurchased
     itemsChan <- items
     return
    }
   }
   errsChan <- nil
   itemsChan <- items
  }()`

Comment: I see I misread your comment and put it right after instead of right before. Testing it.

Comment: (not saying that's the solution, but using good style makes avoiding bugs easier)

Comment: If it's stopping after one a single one finishes, you're not adding enough `wg.Add(1)` calls.   You want to have one immediately preceding _each_ `go func()` call (so, in this case, 6 total).  Oh, and it needs to be before the `go func()`, not within the enclosure, as there's no guarantee that the `wg.Add(1)` in the goroutine will run before `wg.Wait()` gets unblocked by another `wg.Done()`.  If you add it in the main routine, before the `go func()`, it's guaranteed to run first.

Comment: Also, is the `wg.Wait()` blocking indefinitely?  If it isn't, the `wg.Done()` calls are being run.  Your debugger may just not be indicating those lines as being run properly.

Comment: Right, I had one AFTER the start of each one - misread your comment, so it was jumbled. I've now placed a wg.Wait(1) before each go call and then deferred a wg.close. It's not working yet - it just hangs. Debugging to find out where.

Comment: I think wg.Wait() blocks until the waitgroup is zero. Correct? So if all the deferred wg.Done() calls are done after I add the wg.Wait(1)'s, it should unblock, close the channel, and check errors.

Comment: Did you add `wg.Add(1)` or `wg.Wait()`?  `wg.Wait()` will just block, which is bad in this case.

Comment: I have a wg.Wait() after all of the go functions just before closing the channel and checking errors. Currently: http://pastebin.com/WbuKmPTd

Comment: Yes, that's correct, `wg.Wait()` blocks until a number of `wg.Done()` calls are made to equal to the sum of your `wg.Add()` calls.

Comment: Ok, you should only have `wg.Wait()` in the main function.  Should have `wg.Add(1)` _before_ each `go func()` line, and `defer wg.Done()` as the first line in each enclosure.

Comment: And you should only have _one_ `wg.Wait()`, after all the go routines are started, as in the program in your OP.  It's rarely useful to have more than one.

Comment: I only have one in the main (encompassing) function. I linked to a pastebin - it's as you say so far.

Comment: Yep, that pastebin looks correct.  I think your hangup is the for loop, which can put `len(items)` values onto `errsChan`, which the main routine won't read until `wg.Done()` is called enough times, causing a deadlock.  A closer routine might be in order: https://play.golang.org/p/VjYi6rxov5

Comment: You're right - it's the for loop. Trying to fix it with your example. You can probably close the issue since you spotted it as well. Thanks for the help making this ugly code a little more idiomatic!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the sake of posterity (and google searches):

Put `wg.Add(1)` before each `go func()` line, instead of doing it in a single go with `wg.Add(gorutineCt)`

Put `defer wg.Done()` at the start of each goroutine enclosure, instead of calling `wg.Done()` in every exit case.  This ensures `wg.Done()` gets run regardless.

Use a closer routine instead of trying to buffer a channel sufficiently:

```
// start other goroutines

go func () {
    wg.Wait()
    close(errschan)
}

for _, err := range errsChan { // automatically terminates once chan is closed
    if err != nil {
         // handle err
    }
}
```